# Storing 4d array as one file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hdf5

I am working with 4d Arrays (shaped as for example  `(5, 1116, 256, 256)`), for each outer most iteration n in (n,x,x,x) I want the inner 3d array (x,x,x) to be stored as a dataset.

For example: in this case `(5, 1116, 256, 256)`, there should be 5 seperate datasets stored under 1 file.

Is there an easy way to do it ?

Is it possible to create subsets of Numpy Array file and store them under one .npy file ? or should I move towards Hdf5?

Comment: Exactly how are you getting five "datasets" out of a four-element 1D array?

Comment: `np.save` handles 4d arrays just fine; no need for any fancy stuff.  That `5` is just another dimension.  You could, alternatively, split that array into a list of 5 3d arrays, and use `savez` to save them to a `zip` archive, with each 3d as a separate `npy` file.